# Netsuite nlapiTransformRecord

Tags: netsuite

```
    if (latestpayment == 0) {
            var newrecord = nlapiTransformRecord('vendorbill',
                    results[x][7], 'vendorpayment');
            newrecord.setFieldValue('amount', intPayment);
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('documentstatus', 'B');
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('status', 'Paid In Full');
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('statusRef', 'paidInFull');
            newrecord.setFieldValue('account', stRAcctId);
            newrecord.setFieldValue('trandate', stRPostingDate);

            nlapiSubmitRecord(newrecord);
            nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
        } else {
            var newrecord = nlapiTransformRecord('vendorbill',
                    results[x][7], 'vendorpayment');
            newrecord.setFieldValue('amount', intPayment);
            newrecord.setFieldValue('debitamount', payment);
            newrecord.setFieldValue('paidamount', payment);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'payment', payment);
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('documentstatus', 'B');
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('status', 'Paid In Full');
            // newrecord.setFieldValue('statusRef', 'paidInFull');
            newrecord.setFieldValue('account', stRAcctId);
            newrecord.setFieldValue('trandate', stRPostingDate);
            record.setFieldValue('amountpaid', payment);
            record.setFieldValue('amountremaining', intlatestpayment);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'amountremaining', intlatestpayment);

            nlapiSubmitRecord(newrecord);
            nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
```

I have a customized form to submit and all those selected will be transform from vendor bill to vendor payment. I have no issue on this when I do full amount payment and the status will be shown as Paid In Full.

However, when I do partially payment, I cannot do anything and change the status to OPEN. I tried to set the value for both vendor bill and vendor payment record but its doesnt work. Any idea on how to control this partially payment and shown as OPEN with all the amount paid and amount remaining show?

Thank you.

Comment: So this is my understanding- you're trying to make a partial payment and wanted to keep the vendor bill status as open until it gets paid fully.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Exactly. I tried to modified both vendor bill and vendor payment record [amount] related fields but all doesnt work at all..

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but once you transform the record and accept a payment against it doesn't matter whether partial or full the status can not be left as "OPEN". BTW! why do you need the status to be "OPEN"? Is there any specific business needs for as such?

Comment: It can be any other status as long it is not 'Paid In Full'. I am currently creating a page that looks exactly like the default form [Transactions>Payable>Pay Bill] which enable user to select multiple vendor bill in one shot. The reason why I recreate a whole new page is because the default page doesnt allow me to attach any code to it. I have no choice but recreate the form including the logic itself just to attach my code to create a bank bulk processing file logic. And now everything is fine just left this piece where I have to update the bill status accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way to update the amount paid after transform record? I just want it not to be Paid In Full and showing amount remaining that need to pay.

Comment: lets join in chat room.

Comment: Or alternatively, is it possible to create a vendor payment record without transform record?

Comment: I dont think my reputation is enough to join a chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var newrecords = nlapiCreateRecord('vendorpayment', {
                recordmode : 'dynamic'
            });
            newrecords.setFieldValue('entity', aresults[0]
                    .getValue('internalid'));
            newrecords.setFieldValue('account', stRAcctId);
            newrecords.setFieldValue('trandate', stRPostingDate);

            var lineNum = newrecords.findLineItemValue('apply',
                    'internalid', results[x][7]);
            newrecords.selectLineItem('apply', lineNum);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('apply', 'apply', 'T');
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('apply', 'amount', payment);
            newrecords.commitLineItem('apply');

            nlapiSubmitRecord(newrecords, false, false);
            nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
```

Thanks god the above code works. I am able to create a vendor payment record with the code above. Thanks to the link: http://blog.prolecto.com/2013/06/02/automate-creating-checks-to-pay-bills/

It saves my day :)